# returning enum from function in C++ base class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, enums

I came across the following code,

```
class Handler
{
public:
   Handler() {}
   ~Handler() {}

    enum HANDLER_PRIORITY {PRIORITY_0, PRIORITY_1, PRIORITY_2};

    virtual HANDLER_PRIORITY GetPriority();
private:
    HANDLER_PRIORITY m_priority;
}
```

in the .cpp file I have this

```
HANDLER_PRIORITY Handler::GetPrioity()
{
   return PRIORITY_0;
}
```

I get a compilation error, "missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int"

I know that unlinke C, C++ does not support default-int return. but why would it not recognize an enum return type. It works fine if I replace return type from HANDLER_PRIORITY with int/ void, OR if I define the method in the class itself. (inline) OR change the return type to Handler::HANDLER_PRIORITY.

I am on VS 2008.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need

```
Handler::HANDLER_PRIORITY Handler::GetPriority()
{
...
}
```

Edit: Sorry didn't see the rest of your post.  As for why this is the case, `HANDLER_PRIORTY` doesn't have global scope.  It's a member of `Handler` no less than any other.  So of course you have to tell the compiler where it is, i.e. use `Handler::`.

Comment: you could use `return HANDLER_PRIORITY::PRIORITY_0;`  and so forth for returning a specific enum